# Update command with parameters gives "Data type mismatch in criteria expression"

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I have the following code:

```
/*
// it works
cmd_oper = "UPDATE [Model Elements] SET [Record Status] = \"Disabled\" WHERE [Index] = @db_idx";
/*/
// it doesn't work
cmd_oper = "UPDATE [Model Elements] SET [Record Status] = @stat WHERE [Index] = @db_idx";
//*/
using( OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand( cmd_oper, svr_conn ) )
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add( "@db_idx", OleDbType.Integer ).Value = 2;
    //cmd.Parameters.Add( "@stat", OleDbType.VarChar ).Value = "Disabled";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@stat", "Disabled" );
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

With the second variant of cmd_oper (the one not commented in the beginning of the code) I get "Data type mismatch in criteria expression". The other one works. The type of Record Status column is set in database as Short Text. I know there are many posts related to this error on StackOverflow but I couldn't find an exact fit. Thanks.

Comment: With oledb you should provide the parameters in the order they appear in the SQL statement.

Comment: You need to add varchar length to the parameter:cmd.Parameters.Add( "@stat", OleDbType.VarChar, 100 ).Value = "Disabled";

Comment: @mh__ no, it is not necessary, better but not necessary

Comment: OleDb states that parameters' placeholders should be inserted using the ? char. But Access allows named placeholders using the `@something` syntax. (To better scale up to Sql Server?). The really important thing is to insert the parameters values inside the Parameters collection following the order in which the placeholders appear. In the OP case the `@stat` parameter value is used for the Index field raising the exception

Comment: @steve pretty sure that adding length is a sensible measure for some parameter types, and hence a good habit to get into, as the default length for some types is rather low (recently had a guy complaining that only 1 byte of his VarBinary was being saved to the db; he hadn't specified a length

Comment: Length is very important when you work against a server side database with an optimization engine that doesn't recompile your query if it is the same. Without length, strings are passed for their actual length but because they change everytime, the optimization engine fails to reuse the same query already compiled. Access is more limited in this aspect I suppose being a desktop database and the gains are probably minimal. However I agree with you that is a good habit to define also the length for the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fine manual, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx has the following to say about parameters

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
>   parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
>   OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the
>   question mark (?) placeholder must be used. For example:
>
> SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = ?
>
> Therefore, the order in which OleDbParameter objects are added to the
>   OleDbParameterCollection must directly correspond to the position of
>   the question mark placeholder for the parameter in the command text.

Ergo, I think you need your code to be like:

```
cmd_oper = "UPDATE [Model Elements] SET [Record Status] = ? WHERE [Index] = ?";
using( OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand( cmd_oper, svr_conn ) )
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "anything-name-doesnt-matter", "Disabled" );
    cmd.Parameters.Add( "its-position-that-matters", OleDbType.Integer ).Value = 2;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

For what it's worth, you should probably name your parameters sensibly (I named them silly above to demonstrate that the name is irrelevant) because the idea is that once prepared, you can execute a statement many times just changing the parameters:

```
    cmd.Parameters["its-position-that-matters"].Value = 3;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Parameters["its-position-that-matters"].Value = 4;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Parameters["its-position-that-matters"].Value = 5;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Parameters["its-position-that-matters"].Value = 6;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Here i've run the update for `index` values 3, 4, 5 and 6 too, just by changing the parameter value and re-running. It would hence have been better of me to choose a sensible name for the "index" parameter, to make the code more readable

Steve, in his comment, has noted he believes that you *can* put named parameters in the query, but the names are ignored (they're essentially treated as `?` marks anyway) so you'll still need to add the parameter values in the same order as the placeholders appear. If you have repeated a placeholder in a query, you'll have to repeat-add it to the parameters collection. I've no comment on the accuracy of steve's assertion; I've always used `?`

**Ultimately, this is all good evidence that really you should get into learning to use a data access library like Entity Framework, and stop writing SQL strings in your button click event handlers** - it's not a good way to code. If you'd used EF from the outset, you'd never even have hit this problem. Good on you for using parameterised queries though. Now go check out EF and leave this '90s donkey-way of doing data access behind :)